# css3 triangle with up and down

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I need to create 1 div element and in it I need to draw 2 triangles as 1

1) it must be up arrow
2) it must be down arror

but I need add them in 1 class

I understand that I can create 2 classes and then with margin connect them but I need only one class
this is a problem.

can I do this?

Comment: Do you need them positioned side by side or one on top of another. If possible, please provide an image showing what you want.

Comment: the way you're talking about this makes me think you're trying to create a '+' and '-' design... this would need to be made with two elements if you wanted that functionality (since pseudo elements aren't 'physical' elements in the DOM). If it was just for design, you could quickly make this with pseudo elements...[for example](http://jsfiddle.net/7kkrfowp/)

Comment: this is what I need to do
http://s018.radikal.ru/i508/1503/87/bd92ee398e2c.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were looking to make This for design (rather than being functional), you could use pseudo elements:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
div:hover:before,
div:hover:after {
  border-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

If, however, you need this to be actually **functional** (i.e. to register if you need it to be 'pressable' - then you would need to use multiple elements since pseudo elements aren't distinguishable in the DOM for 'key pressing'):

```css
div {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
div .up {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-left: 5px solid tomato;
  border-top: 5px solid tomato;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
div .down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: -5%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom: 5px solid tomato;
  border-right: 5px solid tomato;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
div span:hover {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="up"></span>
  <span class="down"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a square div and just rotate it 45 degrees using CSS `transform`. You can view a live demo of it at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avkuvyLm/)

```
<div class="diamond"></div>

<style>
   .diamond {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
   }
</style>
```

Comment: For information, compatibility: IE9+ according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: no it is not what I need

I need to create like this image
http://s018.radikal.ru/i508/1503/87/bd92ee398e2c.png